# Differentiating with respect to size of index

Tags: derivatives, implicit-differentiation

I have the following function:
$$a\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i. $$
I wish to differentiate with respect to $n$. If all $x_i$s were the same, this problem would be trivial, obviously. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

Depending on how deep you go into integration theory, your question **may not make a lot of sense**.

Notice that you are differentiating with respect to a non continous variable ($n \notin \mathbb R $) but to a discrete variable ($n \in \mathbb N $).

To go further, making sense to this differential would involve distribution theory [wikipedia : Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics))

Comment: I suppose you could turn it into a continuous variable:

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could turn it into a continuous variable as follows:
$$\int_{0}^{\overline{z}}z dz $$. differentiating this expression wrt $\overline{z}$ yields $\overline{z}$?